# Checking if array element is a key

Tags: php, arrays, key, element

How does one loop through an array and then subsequently check to see if the current selected element is a key? Thanks.

E.g. for the following:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
  //if($arr[$i]) == key, or typeOf($arr[$i]) == key, then doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the element value equals key ?

Comment: what do you mean by *"current selected element "* and *"is a key"*

Comment: What do you mean by that? Every element in the array consists of a key and value. Do you mean the value is a key in another array?

Comment: edit the question instead of placing the example in a comment

Comment: `key` is not a datatype or anything in PHP (certainly not a keyword). It's still not clear what you want to do. What is `key` in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if a key exists in an array, then use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
//check if whatever is $key is a key in $array
if(array_key_exists( $key , $array )){
    //do something because it's a key
} else {
    //key not found. not a key
}
```

to do the other way around and get key if value exists, use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

```
$array = array(
    0 => 'blue', 
    1 => 'red', 
    2 => 'green', 
    3 => 'red'
);

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! I sincerely appreciate your answer! However, an additional trouble is acquiring the actual key itself (e.g. "and"=>"word" - how can I get the string of "and" by this means?).  Thanks!

Comment: @user784446: IMO it would be much easier to help you, if you provide an example with the data you have (input) and the result you want to get.

Comment: I'm trying to loop through an array and test to see if either the key or the value to which it's associated passes a strstr test.

Comment: if you want to get the value, use a key. in PHP, you can also get the key using the value. updated my answer.

Comment: @user784446: Then use a `foreach` loop `foreach($arr as $key => $value)`... it seems to be the same problem than your previous question refers to.